# MacBook Pro 13" M1 True Tone and automatic brightness stopped working

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, big-sur, apple-silicon, auto-brightness

I recently noticed a problem with my computer. `TrueTone` and `automatic brightness` stopped working. I tried everything: restart, hard restart, safe mode, system reset, creating a new user. All Mac components are **original** and have not changed.

Computer: `MacBook Pro 13" M1 8CPU|8GPU|16GB|1TB`

Mac OS: `Bug Sur 11.5.2`

Battery: `100%`

That I see in settings:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I have exactly the same issue and searched on internet and found your post. I have M1 Macbook Air 8GB RAM. No matter what I do, the problem is not going away. Any updates from your side?

Comment: I'll try to open the topic on the official website, maybe someone there will help. Or our laptops are defective and we have to go to service centers, spending a lot of time and nerves.

Watch this: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253124969

Comment: One more question. Did you try to use [Apple Configurator 2](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/apple-configurator-2/apdd5f3c75ad/mac) to reset system?

Comment: I tried to run a [diagnostic](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202731) on my mac and got an `ALS 001` error message. From [this source](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203747), it means "There may be an issue with the ambient light sensor." Okay, let's go to the service center, unfortunately, the laptop was still defective.

Comment: Exact same issue, but running a diagnostic give me no error message. M1 Macbook Air 8GB RAM.

Answer (score -1):

Mine wasn't working and it showed the exact same in system reports. I cleaned the glass covering the sensor with a cloth and it is back working again. I'm so dumb i have been trying to find what's wrong for hours.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/313465)